# validate forms with js

Tags: javascript, validation

Hi I had my script working then I ran it through w3 validator and changed what I told me was wrong and now it stops validating at the first postcode, I have stuffed up and cant remember what was changed bigg lesson learnt do 1 thing at a time, I have been pulling my hair out trying to get it working again but cant figure out how if any 1 can take to time to look at it, I would greatly appreciate it, thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>Joes Fruit and Vegetable Store</title>
        <script>
            //calender dropdown menu 
            var monthtext = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

            function populatedropdown(dayfield, monthfield, yearfield) {
                var today = new Date()
                var dayfield = document.getElementById(dayfield)
                var monthfield = document.getElementById(monthfield)
                var yearfield = document.getElementById(yearfield)
                for (var i = 0; i < 31; i++)
                dayfield.options[i] = new Option(i, i + 1)
                dayfield.options[today.getDate()] = new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(), true, true) //select today's day
                for (var m = 0; m < 12; m++)
                monthfield.options[m] = new Option(monthtext[m], monthtext[m])
                monthfield.options[today.getMonth()] = new Option(monthtext[today.getMonth()], monthtext[today.getMonth()], true, true) //select today's month
                var thisyear = today.getFullYear()
                for (var y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
                    yearfield.options[y] = new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
                    thisyear += 1
                }
                yearfield.options[0] = new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true) //select today's year
            }
            // function validate
            function validate_form() {
                valid = true;
                // validate name
                /*   if ( document.input.name.value == "" )
        {
                alert ( "Please enter your name" );
                valid = false;
        }
                                                                // validate address
                if ( document.input.address.value == "" )
        {
                alert ( "Please enter your address address" );
                valid = false;
        }                                                       
                                                                // validate suburb town
                if ( document.input.town.value == "" )
        {
                alert ( "Please enter your Suburb or town" );
                valid = false;
        } 


                                                            // validate postcode        

        var y = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
       if(isNaN(y)||y.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
       {
          alert("Postcode must be in numbers.");
          document.getElementById("postcode").focus();
          return false;
       }

       if (y.length>4 || y.length<4)
       {
            alert("Postcode should be 4 digit");
            document.getElementById("postcode").focus();
            return false;
       }  
        */
                // validate home phone
                var y = document.getElementById('hphone').value;
                if (isNaN(y) || y.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
                    alert("Home Phone number must be in numbers.");
                    document.getElementById('hphone').focus();
                    return false;
                }
                if (y.length > 10 || y.length < 10) {
                    alert("Home Phone number should be 10 digit");
                    document.getElementById('hphone').focus();
                    return false;
                }
                // validate work phone
                var y = document.getElementById('wphone').value;
                if (isNaN(y) || y.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
                    alert("work Phone number must be in numbers.");
                    document.getElementById('wphone').focus();
                    return false;
                }
                if (y.length > 10 || y.length < 10) {
                    alert("Work Phone number should be 10 digit");
                    document.getElementById('wphone').focus();
                    return false;
                }
                // validate fax
                var y = document.getElementById('fax').value;
                if (isNaN(y) || y.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
                    alert("Fax number must be in numbers.");
                    document.getElementById('fax').focus();
                    return false;
                }
                if (y.length > 10 || y.length < 10) {
                    alert("Fax Phone number should be 10 digit");
                    document.getElementById('fax').focus();
                    return false;
                }
                // validate email   
                {
                    var x = document.forms["input"]["email"].value;
                    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
                    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
                    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
                        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                // validate radio buttons
                var o = document.getElementById('rad1');
                var t = document.getElementById('rad2');
                if ((o.checked == false) && (t.checked == true)) {
                    // validate alternative address
                    if (document.input.street.value == "") {
                        alert("Please enter alternative address address");
                        valid = false;
                    }
                    // validate suburb town
                    if (document.input.suburb.value == "") {
                        alert("Please enter alternative Suburb or town");
                        valid = false;
                    }
                } // validate postcode  
                var y = document.getElementById('postcode2').value;
                if (isNaN(y) || y.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
                    alert("Postcode must be in numbers.");
                    document.getElementById('postcode2').focus();
                    return false;
                }
                if (y.length > 4 || y.length < 4) {
                    alert("Alternative Postcode should be 4 digit");
                    document.getElementById('postcode2').focus();
                    return false;
                }
                // validate message box
                var o = document.getElementById('card');
                if ((o.checked == true)) {
                    if (document.input.message.value == "") {
                        alert("Please enter message");
                        valid = false;
                    }
                    return valid;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>  <b>Order form for Joe's Fruit Shop</B><br><br>

<b> * means you must fill in the details.</B><br><br>
<b>Your details:</b>
        <br>
        <br>
        <!-- Beggining of Form -->
        <form name="input" action="cal2.html" onsubmit="validate_form ()">
            <!--name form -->* Name:
            <input type="text" name="name" onclick="this.value='';" value="Enter your name with first">
            <br>
            <br>
            <!-- Address form -->* Address:
            <input type="text" name="address" onclick="this.value='';" value="Enter your street address">
            <br>
            <br>
            <!-- Suburb state dropdown form-->* Suburb or Town:
            <input type="text" name="town" onclick="this.value='';"
            value="suburb">State:
            <select name="state">
                <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="QLD">QLD</option>
                <option value="SA">SA</option>
                <option value="WA">WA</option>
                <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
                <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
                <option value="NT">NT</option>
                <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
            </select>
            <!-- post code form -->* Postcode:
            <input type=text name="postcode" onclick="this.value='';" value="****">
            <br>
            <br>
            <!-- Home phone form-->* Phone:
            <input type=text name="hphone" onclick="this.value='';" value="x-xxxx-xxx">
            <!-- work phone form -->Work phone
            <input type=text name="wphone" onclick="this.value='';" value="x-xxxx-xxx">
            <br>
            <br>
            <!-- Fax form-->*Fax:
            <input type=text name="fax" onclick="this.value='';" value="0x-xxxx-xxx">
            <!-- Email form-->Email address:
            <input type=text name="email" onclick="this.value='';" onsubmit="return validateForm();"
            value="Enter your current email">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <!-- credit card--> <b>Credit card details:</b>
            <br>
            <br>* Type:
            <select name="credit card">
                <option selected="selected" value="AMEX">Amex</option>
                <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
                <option value="Mastercard">Mastercard</option>
            </select>*Expiry date:
            <select name="expiration_month">
                <option value="">Choose...</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="1">January</option>
                <option value="2">Febuary</option>
                <option value="3">March</option>
                <option value="4">April</option>
                <option value="5">May</option>
                <option value="6">June</option>
                <option value="7">July</option>
                <option value="8">August</option>
                <option value="9">September</option>
                <option value="10">October</option>
                <option value="11">November</option>
                <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
            <select name="expiration_year">
                <option value="">Choose...</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                <option value="2019">2019</option>
                <option value="2020">2020</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
             <B>Purchase details</B><br><br>                                    <!-- Product dropdown form-->
* Product:
<select name="product">
<option value="carrot">Bag of carrots</option>
<option value="zucchini">Zucchini</option>
<option value="cabbage">Cabbage</option>
<option value="grapes">Grapes</option>
<option value="tomatoes">TAS</option>
<option value="apples">Apples</option>
<option value="banana">banana</option>
<option selected="selected" value="cucumber">Cucumber</option>
</select>
                                                                <!-- Quantity dropdown form-->
Quantity:
<select name="quantity">
<option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
</select>

<br><br><br>
* <B>Deliver to:</B>
<br><br>
                                                                    <!-- Address Radio buttons-->
<input type='radio' id="rad1" name='radio' value='Home address'  checked="checked">Home Address<br>
<input type='radio' id="rad2" name='radio' value='Other address'/>Other Address<br><br>

                                                                    <!--other address-->

                                                                    <!-- street form-->
Street <input type=text name="street" onclick="this.value='';" value="Street"><br><br>
                                                                    <!-- Suburb form-->
Suburb <input type=text name="suburb" onclick="this.value='';" value="Suburb or town"><br><br>
                                                                    <!-- State dropdown form-->
State <select name="state">
<option value="NSW">NSW</option>
<option selected="selected" value="QLD">QLD</option>
<option value="SA">SA</option>
<option value="WA">WA</option>
<option value="TAS">TAS</option>
<option value="VIC">VIC</option>
<option value="NT">NT</option>
<option value="ACT">ACT</option>
</select><br><br>
                                                                <!-- post code form -->
Postcode:<input type=text name="postcode2" onclick="this.value='';" value="****"><br><br><br>

* Date delivery required:
                                                                    <!-- Calender drop down menu-->

<select id="daydropdown">
</select> 
<select id="monthdropdown">
</select> 
<select id="yeardropdown">
</select> 


<script type="text/javascript">

//populatedropdown(id_of_day_select, id_of_month_select, id_of_year_select)
window.onload=function(){
populatedropdown("daydropdown", "monthdropdown", "yeardropdown")
}
</script>

                                                                    <br><br>
                                                                    <!-- include a card option-->

Include a card: <input type="checkbox" name="card" value="Yes">Yes<br><br>
Personal message on card: <textarea rows="10" name="message" cols="30" onclick="this.value='';" >Enter your personal message here</textarea><br><br>
Click on <b>Submit</b> when done; click on <b> Clear form</b> to reset.
            <!-- submit button-->
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <!-- reset button-->
            <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Indenting your code properly will help you find errors.

Comment: Javascript validation is a bad idea to begin with since it'll do you no good the moment someone with javascript disabled visits your website. Aside from that it's highly unlikely someone will look through your complete script. If you can find a small code sample where the validation issue is reproducable, post that instead.

Comment: @mabako: I'd say JS validation is a very good idea because you're not making requests to the server unless everything is filled correctly. But of course, you need a server validation backup too. Btw, there's under 1% of people with JS disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scripts are failing as you are trying to get elements by Id and checking the value property of a null.

```
 var y = document.getElementById('hphone').value;
```

This throws an exception and exits, the form then submits

Give your elements Ids to match the name attribute and it should be okay

```
 <input type=text name="hphone" id="hphone" onclick="this.value='';" value="x-xxxx-xxx">
```

change your onsubmit attribute to the follow to cancel the submit on validation error

```
<form name="input" action="cal2.html" onsubmit="return validate_form ()">
```

To check against a default value, you could added a data attribute and cross check the value in the validation.

```
* Phone: <input type=text name="hphone" id="hphone" onclick="this.value='';" data-default="x-xxxx-xxx" value="x-xxxx-xxx"> 

var element = document.getElementById('hphone');
var y = element.value;
var defValue = element.attributes["data-default"].value;

if(isNaN(y)||y.indexOf(" ")!=-1|| y === defValue )
{
    alert("Home Phone number must be in numbers.");
    document.getElementById('hphone').focus();
    return false;
}
```

If you are targetting HTML5 compliant browsers you could use the placeholder attribute.
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: Hey thanks your a legend you even answered my other problem that I had, i have decided i should change the validations so they pick alert if the default text is still in the form box's ie: Enter your first name i figured out how to do it for the top ones but im lost at postcode, phone, wphone, fax and email any suggestions or a point in the right direction somewhere ??

Comment: updated answer to give you some pointers.  Out of interest, you might want to look at JQuery validation and JQuery unobtrusive validation plugins.  You shouldn't need to write the validation stuff yourself.

Comment: thanks we its for a assignment on javascript so it has to be js :)

Comment: thanks but no such luck didn't want to work :(, ill keep looking

Comment: The data-default approach didn't work ?  the above hphone code worked for me

Comment: did it hmmm weird I must of put something in wrong I changed to the placeholder that works on everything except the alternative address forms they now come up with the alert even after I add something, ill have another try with the phone 1 and try fix my the placeholder 1 aswell, thanks again for your help im learning lots